# Scattering Of Light- How does it happen with Sun and Earth?

Tags: visible-light

Since the Distance of Light from the Sun in the Horizon Part is High, then the Red light is scattered more. But what happens if the earth rotates on the axis? the Distance will be more but at the same time will the same part(equator) will it experience Sunset every time? And Is this diagram correct of the Sun’s ray for the Blue Light and Red/Orange?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the distance from the Sun to the Earth that matters. The Earth's orbit isn't circular. Distance varies over the year. Yet sunsets are red all year long, and noon isn't.

Instead, it is the distance light travels through the atmosphere. You can see from your diagram that this distance is smaller at noon than sunset.

The reason the distance matters is Rayleigh scattering. Light scatters off small particles of dust in the air. Blue is scattered more than red.

If you look at the Sun at noon, you see less blue than you would in space. Some has been scattered away. You see pretty much all the red.

If you look at a patch of sky at noon, you might think it should be black like it is on the moon. There is no sun in that direction. But the sun shines on the whole atmosphere. Some of that light is scattered towards you, and that is the light you see. The scattered light is blue.

If you look at the sun at sunset, all the blue is scattered away and all that is left is red.

Comment: Can you pls explain the distance light travels through the atmosphere?How the distance varies?Is it because the earth rotates in its axis and distance increases?

Comment: If you look in your diagram, you can see how far light would travel through the atmosphere at noon. That is the part you have colored red. Now imagine somebody standing at the North pole looking at the sun. You can see how much longer the distance is from the ground to the edge of the atmosphere.

Comment: So do we observe sunset and blue sky at the same at different places? Sorry for my Questions, i just want to know these!

Comment: Yes. Your diagram shows that the Sun is straight overhead where the red lines are. On the other side of the world, you show that it is dark because the Sun isn't shining there. That is night. In between, the Sun is on the horizon. It is sunrise or sunset. Google time zone.

Comment: So, If i was staying in equador or some place in the horizon i would be experiencing sunrise or sunset while the person staying in parts above or below horizon would be seeing a blue sky. Is it Correct?

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_1249.html

Comment: Does the sunset and clear blue sky appear simultaneously in different places?

Comment: Yes. It is always noon somewhere. It is always sunset somewhere.